# Сравнение signed и unsigned

Tags: c++, типы-данных, сравнение

Как сравнивать `signed` типы с `unsigned`?

Например, такой код выводит `0`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
int main()
{
    unsigned long long x = 124;
    std::cout << (x >= std::numeric_limits<__int64>::min());
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Привести все к типу со знаком и сравнить:

```
 std::cout << (static_cast<int64_t>(x) >= std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min());
```

Естественно, перед приведением типов, нужно проверить, что unsigned поместится в signed.

Понятно, что такие проверки скажутся на быстродействии, поэтому, следует заранее доказать (формальными методами), что переполнения не будет.

Comment: Есть какая-нибудь стандартная проверка на `unsigned`?

Comment: !is_signed тогда буду использовать лучше

Comment: А как `signed` может не поместиться в `unsigned`? Или речь просто о проверке на отрицательное число?

Comment: @alexolut типы могут быть разной длины в битах.

Comment: @alexolut, поместиться - поместится(количество бит вообще-то одинаковое, вопрос лишь в том, за что отвечает 1 бит: за разряд или за знак):

    char a = -100;
    unsigned char b = a; //156

Comment: @0xFFh если типы отличаются только словом `signed`, `unsigned`, то разрядность безусловно будет одинаковой. Но вот если речь о `unsigned int` и `signed short`, то это не так. С `char` пример вообще неудачный, т.к. знаковость `char` зависит от реализации.